# AWS DMS endpoint cannot talk to RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, dms

I'm scratching my head here trying to understand why my endpoint on DMS cannot talk to a RDS instance.
This is the error I get

```
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to connect Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 08001 NativeError: 101 Message: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.31.30.62", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
```

The replication instance and the RDS are in the same VPC. The Security Group of the RDS instance allows connections to the Postgres port.

And the error is also strange, `no pg_hba.conf entry for host` given I cannot update the `pg_hba.conf`.

I've tested the remote connection from my personal computer and it works fine.

Am I missing something?

EDITED FOUND THE ISSUE
I had to set `SSL mode` to `require`

Thanks folks